# Initializing WebServicesClientProtocol

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap, wse

I'm trying to use the WebServicesClientProtocol class to get a soapcontext to use dimeattachment (which is required for the ticketing system I'm working with). But as soon as I initialize the object Dim webServicesClientProtocol1 As NewWebServicesClientProtocol() as stated verbatim in the documentation for that class, I immediately get the runtime exception WebServiceBindingAttribute is required on proxy classes.

What is the proper way to initialize this class?

Comment: The proper way is to not use it. It's part of WSE, and therefore obsolete. The proper way is to use WCF instead.

Comment: DimeAttachment is part of the WSE package and it's the only way the ticketing system I'm working with accepts attachments.

Comment: Then this would be a great time to dump a ticketing system that requires you to use obsolete software.

Comment: I have no such authority to do that.